# buscar y reemplazar resultado de una lista con linq

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, linq

¿Hay alguna manera de reemplazar el valor de un resultado por otro despues de hacer una sentencia linq? lo que pasa es que en mi sentencia linq en **Status**, hay algunos que me llegan con este resultado "PendingForApprover" pero quiero reemplazarlo por "Pending for approver", quisiera que despues de obtener el resultado, se puede utilizar un find y en base a eso remplazar los valores, antes en mi modelo lo tenia con una data annotation con un display name pero por el motivo de que que ese resultado la voy a transformar en JSON y despues sera traido por server side no esta funcionando ese metodo

Les dejo mis sencencia LINQ

```
  var result = db.document.Select(d => new DocumentViewModel
  {
   DocumentId = d.DocumentId,
   Name = w.name
   ReceivedLogs = d.Logs
   Status = w.Status.toString(),
  .Where(l => l.Status == Status.Received)
  .Select(l => new LogViewModel
  {
     CurrentApprover = l.User,
     NameApprover = l.User.FullName
  }).FirstOrDefault()
  }).ToList();
```

muchas gracias

Comment: vos queres en la misma consulta hacer todo?

Comment: Pues si y no, si no se puede, que se haga aparte

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No se si te he entendido correctamente, si lo que quieres es evaluar el valor de  w.Status y en caso de valer "PendingForApprover" modificarlo por "Pending For Approver",yo lo haría con un operador ternario:

> https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/conditional-operator

```
Status = w.Status.toString()=="PendingForApprover"?"Pending For Approver" :  w.Status.toString();
```

Si la condición se cumple, el valor a asignar será "Pending For Approver" si no, será el que que tenga w.Status.

Espero haberte ayudado, Saludos.